# Relations for Product, FrequenceOfUse and User tables

Tags: database, data-modeling

I have 3 tables:

```
Product (shamppoo, toothpaste,..)
FrequenceOfUse (3 times/day, once/day,...)
User
```

As you can imagine I want to store in a database how much the users use products. What should be the relations between those tables?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Product` and one-to-many relationship between `FrequenceOfUse` and `UserProduct` (the latter being a relationship itself).

Note that there is no consensus on whether relationships can have relationships on their own. So some would prefer to model it as:

1. Entity **User**
2. Entity **Product**
3. Entity **Usage**
4. Entity **FrequenceOfUse**
5. `1-N` relationship: **User** *participates in* **Usage**
6. `1-N` relationship: **Product** *participates in* **Usage**
7. `N-1` relationship **Usage** *is performed with* **Frequence**

Both these models are relationally modeled as:

```
CREATE TABLE user (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, ...)
CREATE TABLE product (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, ...)
CREATE TABLE frequence (id NOT NULL, description TEXT, ...)
CREATE TABLE usage
        (
        user INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (user),
        product INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (product),
        frequence INT NOT NULL REFERENCES frequence,
        PRIMARY KEY (user, product)
        )
```

You may find this post in my blog useful:

- [**What is entity-relationship model?**](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/18/what-is-entity-relationship-model/)

Comment: thanks! I agree, but.. what do you think about the possibility of creating a n-n relationshiop between User and Usage?

Comment: @tirengarfio: of course if you need to track the changes of your users' preferences, like: Alice used the Best Toothbrush once a day in 2009, twice a day in 2010, etc. You'll need to add a surrogate primary key to `Usage` as well in this case.